# Play Framework sbt-concat does not work with wildcard setting

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, sbt-web, sbt-concat

I was trying to bundle all css under a directory and its sub-directories. However, I found that only the files under direct level of the specified directory would be bundled, but not the ones in sub-directories.

Then, I tried something like this to indicate that it is for everything including 
"lib.css" -> group(((sourceDirectory in Assets).value / "css" / "core" / "lib") * "**/*.css")
This is not working for me.

I opened up an issue in github already and I hope it will be fixed soon.  However, I would like know if anyone out there already has a solution and would be great if he can share.
https://github.com/ground5hark/sbt-concat/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

You're using `/`. You probably want `**`.

Check out the [`PathFinder` docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.PathFinder):

```
def /(literal: String): PathFinder
Constructs a new finder that selects all paths with name literal that are immediate children of paths selected by this finder.

def **(filter: FileFilter): PathFinder
Constructs a new finder that selects all paths with a name that matches filter and are descendants of paths selected by this finder.
```

So you probably want something like this:

```
(sourceDirectory in Assets).value / "css" / "core" / "lib" ** "*.css"
```